# Error running `Invoke-Command`

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the below command in powershell

> `Invoke-Command -Computer 'someComputer' ScriptBlock {Remove-Item $args -Force -Recurse} -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\someUser\AppData\Local\Temp'`

but getting the below exception.

> `Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Remove-Item $args -Force -Recurse'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-Command -Computer 'someComputer' ScriptBlock {Remove-Item $arg ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand`

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName  'someComputer' -ScriptBlock {Remove-Item $args -Force -Recurse} -ArgumentList {'C:\Users\someUser\AppData\Local\Temp'}
```

1. Invoke command does not have '-computer', it is -ComputerName ,
2. scriptblock is also a command-line option so should be passed as
       -ScriptBlock
3. -Argument list expects a list, so should be passed inside {}

Comment: Thanks. I was missing two things `-ComputerName` instead of `-Computer` and `-` before the ScriptBlock.